# How to check if whole words from string are contained in other string?

Tags: python, string, substring

I want my program to return True if one word from a string is the same as a word in another string, but only when the whole word is matching and not single letters or parts. Here's an illustration on what I mean...

```
a = "hi please help"
b = "help anyone"

if any(a.split()) == any(b.split()):
    print("True")
```

this works for the time being, but if I swap a for something else...

```
a = "h"
b = "help"

if any(a.split()) == any(b.split()):
    print("True")
```

it still prints "True", which is not my intention.
I did look at other similar threads to this, but I couldn't find any that solved the problem where parts are not accepted, but the whole string doesn't have to be a substring.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set_a = set(a.split())
any(w in set_a for w in b.split())
```

This will evaluate to `True` if any word `w` from `b.split()` is in `set_a`, where `set_a` is a set of words formed from `a.split()`.

This should be faster than doing set intersection, since (1) it only creates a set for one of the split strings, (2) it stops searching as soon as a match is found, and (3) it doesn't create a set for the intersection result.

Answer (score 1):

Convert both strings to sets and create an intersection:

```
if set(a.split()) & set(b.split()):
    print("True")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for i in b.split():
  if a.split().count(i):
    print("True")
```

Comment: `a.split().count(i)` is more expensive than `i in a.split()` and to do `a.split()` each turn is expensive too. Your proposal can also print True several times

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `any([e in a.split() for e in b.split()])`